# USSD received message decoding

Tags: c#, decode, at-command, ussd, ucs2

I'm sending AT+CUSD command to a modem and when i receive this message i can't
understand it nor decoding it in any way please i need help.
this is a sample

```
AT+CUSD=1,"*100#",15
+CUSD: 0,"Service not allowed.",15
OK
AT+CUSD=1,"*155#1#",15
+CUSD: 0,"0645063306280642002006270644062F06410639003A00200037002C003600320035002E0030003000200020000A06270644063506440627062D064A0629003A0030002E0030003000200020000A00200627064406440627062D0642002006270644062F06410639003A0030002E003000300020",72
OK
```

you see first is readible and dcs is 15 but the other one isn't and tha dcs is 72 help !!

Comment: Have you tried decoding this long string of numbers using various common coding schemes (GSM 7 bit, UCS2....) to see if you can make some sense out of it?

Comment: Yes, It didn't work with me.
by the way this response must be in arabic.

Comment: What do you get when you decode it using Unicode?  I can see a lot of 06's, and according to Wikipedia, standard Arabic is encoded from 0600 - 06FF.

Comment: Thanks Mr.S List

you helped me finding the sulotion. as you have said it is like every four make a 16bit unicode character but in unicode i get something like

مسبق!الدفع:!  7,625.00! !

but in UCS-2 i get

مسبق الدفع: 7,625.00

which is correct thanks its solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do you get when you decode it using Unicode? I can see a lot of 06's, and according to Wikipedia, standard Arabic is encoded from 0600 - 06FF. S List

The answer thanks to [S List](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725145/s-list)

is that I need to decode every four letters like "0645"
using "UCS2" encoding.

and my code is like this :

```
String origin = "0645063306280642002006270644062F06410639003A00200037002C003600320035002E0030003000200020000A06270644063506440627062D064A0629003A0030002E0030003000200020000A00200627064406440627062D0642002006270644062F06410639003A0030002E003000300020";
if (origin.Count() % 2 == 0)
            {
                List<short> list = new List<short>();
                List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
                var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("UCS-2");
                for (int i = 0; i < origin.Count(); i += 4)
                {
                    list.Add(Convert.ToInt16(origin.Substring(i, 4), 16));
                }
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    bytes.Add((byte)(item & 255));
                    bytes.Add((byte)(item >> 8));
                }
                return encode.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
            }
```